# Embedding ServiceStack dll to Mono Executable

Tags: c#, .net, mono, servicestack

I''m trying to get a program i wrote in C# to work w/ Mono.

The project is here -- https://github.com/micahasmith/cstatic

I have the build script to "mono make" it set up like so--

```
dmcs -r:../packages/ServiceStack.Text.3.9.48/lib/net35/ServiceStack.Text.dll \ 
-target:exe -out:cstatic.exe  \
`find . -name "*.cs"`
```

That builds fine and makes the cstatic.exe. However, when i go to run it like so

`mono cstatic.exe` i get the following:

```
Missing method ToJson in assembly /Users/micahasmith/Downloads/cstatic/CStatic/CStatic/cstatic.exe, type ServiceStack.Text.StringExtensions

Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ServiceStack.Text, Version=3.9.45.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'ServiceStack.Text, Version=3.9.45.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ServiceStack.Text, Version=3.9.45.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'ServiceStack.Text, Version=3.9.45.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to have the servicestack dll in the same folder as the mono generated exe file.